# Probability that one chi-squared random variable is less than other chi-squared random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two random variable 
$X=\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Y=\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2) $ independent to each other.

Now, $Z=X^2$ and $W=Y^2$, are chi-square random variable with first degree of freedom.

My aim is to determine $Prob(Z<W)$.

$f_X(x)=\frac {1} {\sqrt(2\pi\sigma^2)} exp^  {\frac {-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} }$ and 
$f_Y(y)=\frac {1} {\sqrt(2\pi\sigma^2)} exp^{\frac {-y^2}{2\sigma^2}} $

For $W=Y^2$, pdf of chi-square distribution is $f_W(w)=\frac {1} {\sqrt(2\pi\sigma^2w)}  exp^ \frac {-w} {2\sigma^2}$

However, for $Z=X^2$, I don't know how to find $f_Z(z)$. I know, we can use R.V. transformation $V=\frac {X-\mu} \sigma,  $ but slightly confused.

Now, $prob(Z<W)=\int prob(Z<w)f_W(w)dw=\int F_Z(w)f_W(w)dw$. (Please verify this.)

Please help me in the derivation.

Comment: By symmetry the probability is $1/2$.

Comment: You should revise your question because $Z$ is only chi-square distributed if $X$ is a **standard normal** random variable; here, $X$ has some general mean $\mu$, thus $X^2$ is not in general chi-square.

Comment: @d.k.o. Please reconsider your decision to delete your answer because it works even when $X$ and $Y$ are _not_ normal random variables whereas my answer works only for normal random variables. You could edit your answer to emphasize this aspect....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

Show that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are *independent* $N(\mu,2\sigma^2)$ random variables.  (This is easier to do than you might suspect).  Then,

\begin{align}
P\{X^2 < Y^2\} &= P\{X^2-Y^2 < 0\}\\
&= P\{(X+Y)(X-Y) < 0\}\\
&= P\{X+Y > 0, X-Y < 0\} + P\{X+Y < 0, X-Y > 0\}\\
&= P\{X+Y > 0\}P\{X-Y < 0\} + P\{X+Y < 0\}P\{X-Y > 0\}
\end{align}

where the last step follows from the independence of $X+Y$ and $X-Y$.
Note that all four probabilities on that last right side above
can be expressed in terms of the standard cumulative probability
distribution function $\Phi(\cdot)$ of the standard normal
random variable.

Comment: Your solution is much simpler than I originally thought. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

After following Dilip Sarwate's solution

$P\{X^2<Y^2\}=P\{X+Y>0\}P\{X-Y<0\}+P\{X+Y<0\}P\{X-Y>0\}$

Assume $W=X+Y$ and $Z=X-Y$;

It can be shown that $W = \mathcal N(\mu, 2\sigma^2)$ and $Z = \mathcal N(\mu, 2\sigma^2)$

$P\{X+Y>0\}=P\{W>0\}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi*2\sigma^2)} exp^{\frac{-(w-\mu)^2}{2*2\sigma^2}} dw$

Now $m=\frac{w-u}{\sqrt2\sigma}$   $dm=\frac{dw}{\sqrt2 \sigma}$

$w \to 0 \ \ m \to- \frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma} $  and $w \to \infty \ \ m \to \infty $

Therefore, $P\{W>0\}=\int_{- \frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)} exp^{-\frac {m^2}{2}}dm$

$Q(z)=\int_z^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)} exp^{-\frac {y^2}{2}}dy$

Therefore, $P\{X+Y>0\}=P\{W>0\}=Q(-\frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma})$

The same result applies to $P\{X-Y>0\}=P\{Z>0\}=Q(-\frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma})$

Similarly we can find

$P\{X+Y<0\}=P\{W<0\}=Q(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma})$ and $P\{X-Y<0\}=P\{Z<0\}=Q(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma})$

Therefore,
$P\{X^2<Y^2\}=P\{X+Y>0\}P\{X-Y<0\}+P\{X+Y<0\}P\{X-Y>0\}$

$=Q(-\frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma})Q(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma})+Q(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma})Q(-\frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma})$

$=2*Q(-\frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma})Q(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma})$

But $Q(-z)=1-Q(z)$

Therefore, $P\{X^2<Y^2\}=2*{Q(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma})}\{1-Q(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt2 \sigma})\}$

Can anybody verify the proof?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my hints as the answer. Yes, what you have written above is correct, but once again, you are missing the forest while carefully cutting down multiple trees. Since $Z$ and $W$ are _identically_ distributed, $P(W>0)$ and $P(Z<0)$ are _complementary_ probabilities: their sum is $1$. Thus, $P(X^2<Y^2)$ is necessarily of the form $2p(1-p)$ and so we need find only _one_ probability. It is a standard result that for $T \sim N(a,b^2)$, $$P(T\leq c) = \Phi\left(\frac{c-a}{b}\right) = Q\left(\frac{a-c}{b}\right)$$ but working out the details one more time by hand is OK too.